# how to get files uploaded by multer

Tags: node.js, multer

I uploaded files to a folder in back-end using a node library.Now I want to get files from that folder by filename,from a one route.[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNUmn.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you really need.
But you may use nodejs file system to do such a thing (https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback

```js
fs.readFile('/your/file', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
})
```

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback

```js
fs.readdir('/your/directory/path', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: 'file' in path means file name?

Comment: Yes, it means the file name for fs.readFile.
And for directory name it is for fs.readdir.